# Unable to serialize DataTable.DefaultColumn with type of Enum

Tags: c#, xml, enums, dataset

I am trying to serialize a DataSet to XML, and provide a default value on a column that is an Enum.  It appears that .NET is unable to cast the serialized value (int) to the enum value.

Is it possible to have the DataColumn.DefaultValue assigned to an enum through the serializer?  Currently I have a work around implemented where the DefaultValue is manually assigned on the consumer of the XML.

Here is the sample code that fails.

```
public enum Foo
{
    Bar = 0
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
            using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
            {
                dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

                DataColumn column = table.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(Foo));
                column.DefaultValue = Foo.Bar;

                dataSet.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            }

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                dataSet.ReadXml(stream);

                DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
                DataColumn column = table.Columns["Foo"];
                Console.WriteLine(column.DefaultValue.GetType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the exception that results due to the DataSet.ReadXml method call.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The DefaultValue for column Foo is of type System.Int32, but the column is of type ConsoleApplication80.Foo. --->
 System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'ConsoleApplication80.Foo'.
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Int32.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.Common.SqlConvert.ChangeType2(Object value, StorageType stype, Type type, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   at System.Data.Common.SqlConvert.ChangeTypeForDefaultValue(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   at System.Data.DataColumn.set_DefaultValue(Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.DataColumn.set_DefaultValue(Object value)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem, DataTable table, Boolean isBase)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleDataSet(XmlSchemaElement node, Boolean isNewDataSet)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, DataSet ds)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXSDSchema(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, Boolean denyResolving)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(Stream stream)
   at ConsoleApplication80.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\jonathan.berube\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication80\ConsoleApplication80\Program.cs:line 39
```

Also for reference here is the output XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Foo" type="xs:int" default="0" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the underlying type of your enum values are int32 you will need to do something  like what I  did below. You could also make the column type on your table an string and just default is value to Foo.Bar.ToString() .

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                using (DataTable table = new DataTable("Mytable"))
                {

                    dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

                    DataColumn column = table.Columns.Add("Foo", Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Foo)));
                    column.DefaultValue= Foo.Bar;
                   dataSet.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
                }

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }
            using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                dataSet.ReadXml(stream);

                DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];
                DataColumn column = table.Columns["Foo"];
                Console.WriteLine(column.DefaultValue.GetType());
            }
```